# How to represent choice conditions with parameters in Coq

Tags: coq

I have the following code :

```
Definition trans := nat -> nat -> Prop.

Definition ifelse (b : nat -> nat -> bool) (P Q : trans) : trans :=
  fun s1 s2 => if b s1 s2 then P s1 s2 else Q s1 s2.
```

The **ifelse** indicate that if the boolean condition is true, then the proposition *P s1 s2* is selected, otherwise the proposition **Q s1 s2** is established. The boolean condition also depends on the parameter *s1* and *s2*.

I want to prove the traditional theorems that

> IF b THEN P ELSE Q  = IF not b THEN Q ELSE P.

Can anyone give me some ideas how to present this theorem?

Answer (score 2):

The fact that `b`, `P` and `Q` take parameters in your code is not too important. You can just use the following result:

```
Lemma if_swap T (b : bool) (x y : T) :
  (if b then x else y) = if negb b then y else x.
Proof. now destruct b. Qed.
```